# psycopg2.DataError: value too long for type character varying(50)

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

When executing my code i get an error as follows:

```
File "c:/not/test/xmlDB.py", line 27, in <module>
element.getAttribute("kodATC")
psycopg2.DataError: value too long for type character varying(255)
```

My code in python is:

```
for element in rc:
if element.getAttribute("rodzajPreparatu") == "ludzki":
    if len(element.getAttribute("kodATC")) > 50:
        print(len(element.getAttribute("kodATC")))
        print(element.getAttribute("kodATC"))
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO leki VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, 
    %s, %s)", 
    (element.getAttribute("id"), 
    element.getAttribute("nazwaProduktu"), 
    element.getAttribute("nazwaPowszechnieStosowana"),
    element.getAttribute("moc"),
    element.getAttribute("postac"),
    element.getAttribute("podmiotOdpowiedzialny"),
    element.getAttribute("typProcedury"),
    element.getAttribute("numerPozwolenia"),
    element.getAttribute("waznoscPozwolenia"),  
    element.getAttribute("kodATC")         
    ))
```

And the column lenght of column "kodATC" in my Postgres database is set to (255).

The part which prints the value and lenght prints the following output:

```
63
V01AA05;V01AA02;V01AA04;V01AA11;V01AA20;V01AA10;V01AA08;V01AA01
```

So its clearly not longer than (255).
However when i execute the following query in pgAdmin it works just fine:

```
INSERT INTO public.leki VALUES (100085341,'Novo-Helisen Depot','Wyciągi 
alergenowe roztoczy kurzu domowego','-','zawiesina do wstrzykiwań','Allergopharma GmbH & Co. KG','NAR','00011','Bezterminowy','V01AA05;V01AA02;V01AA04;V01AA11;V01AA20;V01AA10;V01AA08;V01AA01');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The traceback is showing `element.getAttribute("kodATC")` because that's the last line of the `cur.execute()` call. But it could be *any* of the values which is causing the errors.

Print the length of the other attributes to see which one is causing the problem.

Comment: The biggest number that shows is 63 and each field has a lenght of 255 also i posted the values it inserts below the code in the sql query example.

Comment: Also it doesnt say database eror but psycopg2.DataError: so i thought the reason behind this isnt the collumn specification.

Comment: *The biggest number that shows is 63* - the code you have shown is only checking the length of `kodATC` - you aren't checking the length of the other values that you are trying to insert. I don't understand your comment about [`DataError`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/module.html#psycopg2.DataError) - it's a subclass of `DatabaseError`. Try changing the `cur.execute(...)` to `print cur.mogrify(...)`. That will show you the actual query that your code is trying to run.

Comment: i meant after i checked the lenght of other variables sorry for being not being specific and it prints as i typed before "INSERT INTO leki VALUES ('100085341', 'Novo-Helisen Depot', 'Wyci\xc4\x85gi alergenowe roztoczy kurzu domowego', '-', 'zawiesina do wstrzykiwa\xc5\x84', 'Allergopharma GmbH & Co. KG', 'NAR', '00011', 'Bezterminowy', 'V01AA05;V01AA02;V01AA04;V01AA11;V01AA20;V01AA10;V01AA08;V01AA01')"

Comment: Ok it was rly a case of another collumn data being too long thanks for the help!

Comment: You didn't say how you got that SQL query from the comment/question. I think it's unlikely that's the query that was causing the error.